# Excel editing from 'Protected View' causes 'run-time error 5'

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro-enabled spreadsheet (Excel 2010) that works fine, unless you're sending it to somebody through the internet. If sending it, the recipient has to 'enable editing' in Protected View and then it throws an error.

"Run-time Error 5"

So my code is pretty simple, I'm making an office bracket for the World Cup. All I'm trying to do is have the user click on a country name in a matchup and have that name populate in the next cell. And it works, unless like I said, I'm sending out through email.

Here is my code. Does anyone know any way I can get the protected view to disable?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r, c, n As Integer
If InRange(ActiveCell, Range("B2:B37")) Or InRange(ActiveCell, Range("F2:F37")) _
Or InRange(ActiveCell, Range("J2:J37")) Or InRange(ActiveCell, Range("N2:N37")) _
Or InRange(ActiveCell, Range("R2:R37")) Or InRange(ActiveCell, Range("V2:V37")) Then
   r = ActiveCell.Row
   c = ActiveCell.Column
   If r Mod 2 = 1 Then
       Cells(r - 1, c + 1).Value = Cells(r, c).Value
   Else
       Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Cells(r, c).Value
   End If
End If
End Sub
```

and then my function below that:

```
Private Function InRange(range1 As Range, range2 As Range) As Boolean
Set intersectrange = Application.Intersect(range1, range2)
InRange = Not intersectrange Is Nothing
Set intersectrange = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the macro is running before an expected cell is selected.  You could add the line

> If Len(ActiveCell) < 1 then exit sub

to the beginning of your code.  That way if an expected cell isn't selected, it wouldn't error out on you, and it won't run until the user selects a valid cell.

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thanks. In the function below, I say "If range1 Is Nothing Then Exit Function" at the top.